# Execute Webdriver test from CMD

Tags: selenium, cmd, webdriver

Does any easy way exist to execute **WebDriver** tests using CMD? 
I use this command to execute Selenium test suite on Selenium RC:

> java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://url"
>   "test_suite.html" "results.html"

And I need something similar for WebDriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your project up as a Maven project and it's as simple as running `mvn test`

Then, depending on the framework you're using, you can use various command line arguments to change the tags/suites you are running via command line.